# Time based workflow actions

Tags: workflow, time-dependent-workflow

In my scenerio I have created a time based workflow action which would send an email to owner of an opportunity based on a criteria. The workflow action send email after 15 days. Many of my records were created or update which met the criteria in workflow rule and whose owner are scheduled to receive an email after 15 days. Since this workflow was created very recently, I would like to change 15 days to 10 days in my workflow action. If I change that would the existing record which are untouched, will there owner get the email after 10 days or 15 days?

The workflow rule will trigger when record is created or edited only. I guess logically the record which were edited or created when 15 days rule was active , will get email after 15 days only. If I change the rule to 10 days and hit edit/save on the record which meets the criteria, will the owner now get an email with in 10 days?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I dont think you are allowed to change the time triggers if you have old records pending actions in the queue. You can check the limitations here on the salesforce documentation.

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=workflow_time_action_considerations.htm&language=en_US

Comment: What if I deactivate the workflow rule and then make an edit to the time based action? I read there is a time based queue which might have the time based action in it even though the workflow rule is deactivated. Is this correct?

Comment: Even if you deactivate the rule you cannot change the time on the time trigger. You can change the actions on the time trigger but not the actual time. That will only happen if you do not have any actions pending in the queue.